# Achieving a tunable parameter in OpenModelica

Tags: openmodelica, fmi

I have the following Modelica code

```
model RocketCar
  Real x;
  Real v;
  input Real u(min = -1, max = 1);
  parameter Real h;
equation
  der(x) = h*v;
  der(v) = h*u;
end RocketCar;
```

meant to model the infamous [rocket car](http://prac.im.pwr.edu.pl/~hugo/HSC/imprezy/EMS_school2010/wachsmuth_lecture.pdf) problem, which I would like to transform into an FMU.
I transform the file using `OMShell`:

```
>>> loadFile("RocketCar.mo")
true 
>> translateModelFMU(RocketCar)
"/path/to/RocketCar.fmu"
```

The resulting FMU lists the variable as

```
<ScalarVariable
  name="h"
  valueReference="10"
  variability="fixed"
  causality="parameter"
  initial="exact">
  <Real start="0.0"/>
</ScalarVariable>
```

i.e., as a fixed parameter. I would like to change the Modelica code to obtain a `tunable parameter` in the resulting FMU.

Note that a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29674409/fmu-export-in-dymola-is-it-possible-to-make-a-modelica-enumeration-type-variabl) has been asked and answered already. The suggested solution was to add `annotation (Evaluate=false)` to the definition of the parameter. However, this answer seems to be specific to [Dymola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dymola). The suggested annotation seems to have no effect regarding the resulting FMU. Is there an OpenModelica variant of the annotation to achieve the same effect?